# Spark executor log in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: apache-spark, logging, intellij-idea, executor

I'm running a spark application which has dependency of spark in pom. And in IntelliJ IDEA, I can only see the log of driver side but no executor log. I find in the configuration I can add log files to be showed in the console, but I need to know where the log file is located...Please note it use the spark in dependency libraries but not my local spark environment...

Thanks,
Lionel

Comment: My OS is OS X EI Capitan version 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the executor logging. Take a look into this - http://shzhangji.com/blog/2015/05/31/spark-streaming-logging-configuration/